# jQuery menu widget - pop up upwards on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery menu widget which contains a single root entry and several sub entries. I want it to behave as follows:

- It shouldn't open on hover but on click
- It shouldn't open to the side but upwards

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#menu").menu({ trigger: "click" });
```

That will change the event that triggers the menu from "hover" to "click"

I am assuming by "It shouldn't open to the side by upwards" you mean the sub menu should appear below the selected main menu option, expanding the height of the main menu. However, this is an assumption; If you could clarify your requirements I will come back and edit my answer.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your code but it didn't make a difference. Do I have to do anything else? By upwards I mean the submenu should open above the main menu and not to the right. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hover event you would use click event. And most of the time direction of the sub menus or menu item contents is defined with absolute position so in your case you would define the position in a way where you would define a top negative position, where value would be the height of your hidden content.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an absolute beginner. How can I influence the position? And how do I use the click instead of the hover event? I just have a bunch of ul and li elements and call the jQuery menu() function on the root ul.

Comment: Regarding the position there is an explanation in jquery ui menu api. You can find it [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position) And to help you with click instead of hover let me see some exact code you are using. Put it on jsFiddle.